# Countbold function error on Excel

Tags: excel, count

I have absolutely no Microsoft Excel experience and borrowed a CountBold macro and pasted it as a module into Excel. The function worked. However, when I closed the sheet and reopened it, it the #NAME? error comes out due to "unrecognized text". I've pasted the code below. Please help!

```
Function CountBold(WorkRng As Range)
'Update 20131202
Dim Rng As Range
Dim xCount As Long
For Each Rng In WorkRng
If Rng.Font.Bold Then
xCount = xCount + 1
End If
Next
CountBold = xCount
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess that your spreadsheet is an XLSX. You need to saveas and choose a Macro enabled workbook (XLSM) then it will retain the macro (function) when you close and save it